# How to make charge using stripe in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I have read all detail about stripe integration in iOS app [from here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios). And run the sample app of stripe by downloading [from here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example).

On running this app, I am getting following error when I am testing on iPhone Simulator.

[image]

Following method is calling after token received::

```
- (void)hasError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
                                                      message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}


//--Called after sucessfully token received ::
- (void)hasToken:(STPToken *)token
{
    NSLog(@"Received token %@", token.tokenId);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSString *body     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stripeToken=%@", token.tokenId];
    request.HTTPBody   = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

                               if (error) {
                                   [self hasError:error];

                               } else {

                                   NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   NSLog(@"\nStr is :::%@",str);

                                   NSLog(@"\n\nResponse is :::%@",response);

                                   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                               }
                           }];
}
```

Please tell me how to resolve this problem and make a credit card payment on iOS app because in this sample code, there is information about payment.

Comment: Here's a tutorial and a sample app that may help you: http://monolithapps.com/blog/accept-mobile-credit-card-payments-with-stripe.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `example.com`. Replace it first with your own server address.

Answer (score 0):

For charging a card in Stripe you need a server module. [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) is detail explanation of how to charge your card via server module. If you are using parse as backend you can always use cloudcode for this purpose.

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe) is raywenderlich's explanation of making payment system with python backend.